# RMariaDB doesn't seem to allow me to connect to a MySQL server

Tags: mysql, r, rmariadb

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server from R. I'm using the RMariaDB package and I keep getting the following error.

Error: Failed to connect: Plugin https could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found. Library path is '/mingw64/lib/mariadb/plugin/https.dll'

I've tried searching and got nothing. I've also tried looking for that dll on the system and can't seem to find it, so it'd appear that I'm missing some files. But I've tried reinstalling R and I still had the problem, so I'm really not sure how to proceed.
I don't even have a mariadb folder under mingw64, assuming it's the mingw64 folder under rtools I need to look in, so perhaps that's where my problem is.

I'm wondering if there perhaps is something else I need to install aside from the DBI and RMariaDB packages. I also installed ODBC just in case that was what was needed, but that didn't change anything.

Here's the code I used to connect to the database. I think it should be correct, but perhaps I made a mistake somewhere.

```
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
     host = "URL_to_DB",
     user = "user_name",
     password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
  )
```

Comment: Why do you use `RMariaDB` and not `RMySQL`?

Comment: Have you looked at this https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-gssapi/

Comment: Seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60094669/6574038) @Waldi?

Comment: @Waldi Actually it worked for me using `RMySQL`. With my comment I meant to ask if it''s not just a temporary luck. Please my see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70914083/6574038)